# Pagination using jquery in Jsp page

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts-1

i want paging using jquery in jsp page.

i want page wise navigation and data should come dynamically. as well when i m going to click on page number at that time data should load..it must not be preloaded.

Also the whole page must not be reloaded..it should be ajax based.

I am using struts 1.2.

you can suggest ajax implementation with struts display tag also.

Please suggest.

similar like [ingrid](http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/src/example3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Then use DisplayTag in your Project

DisplayTag is Third party plugin just Download and add it to Project.
for more information and Tutorials [Click Here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-display-tag-table-decorator-example-1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of jquery pagination plugins. Choose what's best suits you.

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/#.UAPPVEjfszI

Answer (score 0):

try jPaginate

It is a jQuery pagination plugin that comes with a twist: animated page numbers. The user can slide through the available page numbers by clicking or just hovering over the arrows. Shortlinks to the first and last page are available as well.

http://ankitchauhan22.blogspot.in/2010/01/pagination-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

This page http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/10/jquery-pagination-plugins.html has 20 jquery plugins, I recommend you to go and find the most suitable.